# How to see the source code inside the library when doing ctrl+click(go to definition) in vscode (python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, go-to-definition

I know that in vscode, we can find the definition of variable/function by ctrl+clicking. Ctrl+click also supports that for variables/functions declared inside the libararies we've installed.(e.g. torch, numpy, ..)

In my vscode, the 'go to definition' in my own file is available, but I can't click variables defined in libraries.

I want variables/functions of libraries also searchable by ctrl+clicking. How do I make it also available?

Comment: same issue for me, although pylance is installed and the interpreter set correctly (the current answers). My workaround is currently to ctrl+click the library instead (i.e. if the function is `foo.bar.func()` i can not click func or bar, but i can click `foo`. Then that library's init file opens and at the top in vscode the path to it appears. clicking on there gives a dropdown choice for selecting `bar`. in there, finally, I search for `func`

Answer (score 4):

If you install the libraries in your virtual environments, You should change the python interpreter to your `virtualenv` that you use from bottom right side of the vscode and then `alt+click` can help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a function provided by pylance.

You can install [pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) extension.

[image]